# Setting up Country Restrictions for Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem,

I have a Facebook App which target audience is the US. I want to use Coutnry Restrictions in 'Advanced Settings' so that only people from the US can log into my App.

It appears that whenever I do that, some of my team members ( who are not from the US ), cannot log in into my App... even if they have 'Administrator' role.

How can I allow the 'out of US' developers of my App to still be able to login to it ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) has information on country even when the person hasn't logged in.

You can use it to restrict users.

```
Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [issued_at] => 1338280574 [page] => Array ( [id] => 171340959572434 [liked] => 1 [admin] => ) [user] => Array ( [country] => in [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 ) ) )
```

OR

You can add multiple countries to allow. so you will have to allow your developers country as well and show some error message by using above method for those developers country people